# How Can I Approach Machine Learning in Python, Simply?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am a web developer and tools creator professionally. The way that I learn things is by making the smallest possible product that is still functional and useful, and then adding complexity / refactoring as needed. I am trying to learn data science and pick up machine learning skills. When I look at the "small" projects in Machine Learning they assume a knowledge of Numpy, Pandas, and Seaborn in addition to being well versed in Python.

How can I make the machine learning equivalent of an index.html with Hello World inside of an `<h1>` tag?

If this is not possible, what sorts of projects can I do to incrementally "master" the underlying libraries. i.e. What is a "useful" project that one can do with only Numpy, only Numpy + Pandas, only Numpy + Pandas + Seaborn etc?

Apologies for open ended-ness. Not sure where else to post a question like this.

Comment: "Not sure where else to post a question like this." This is not the place.

Comment: Unfortunately, not being able to come up with a different site to post it does not magically make it appropriate to ask here. Please see [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If you happen to find a good site for this kind of question let me know, I always wanted to ask for the "Hello world" equivalent of building my own space shuttle :-)

Answer (score 0):

In response to the latter question

"What is a "useful" project that one can do with only Numpy, only Numpy + Pandas, only Numpy + Pandas + Seaborn etc?"

Numpy Projects in Isolation:

http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/numpy.100/index.html

Projects here start very minimally and move into more and more complex problem spaces using on numpy as the only tool.

Numpy and Pandas Projects in Isolation:

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/data-manipulation-visualisation-r-python/tutorial-data-manipulation-numpy-pandas-python/tutorial/

This link contains a short introduction to numpy and then spends the bulk of its resources discussing data frames.

Both links have the user solve increasingly complex data frame manipulations and were awesome resources to me and gave me lots of ideas on way I could expand and add additional complexity.